# NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT changing automatically and randomlly

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am using Oracle 11gR2. My `nls_timestamp_format` is changing randomly from `dd-mon-rr` to `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: *When* is it changing automatically?

Comment: When is it differing? Are you aware that tools/libraries are able to change it with an "alter session" and this may be happening in the background (depending on the tool), upon login for example.

Comment: I am using sqlplus to connect, the nls_timestamp_format parameter is changing randomly from dd-mon-rr to yyy/mm/dd.

Comment: You could turn on auditing: "AUDIT ALTER SESSION BY <username> BY ACCESS" and follow the DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL to see when this happens

Comment: What do you mean *randomly*? After login? Or on each login?

Comment: On each login it changes Colin.

Comment: If it's only after each login in SQL*Plus then the most logical place it's happening is in glogin.sql or login.sql (as haki mentions in his answer). See also http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/login.html

Comment: Never rely on the system default for NLS values. Always specify them as part of the session creation or in the code itself.

Comment: Hi David,I am using sqluldr2 utility to unload data which doesnt allow to change any session level parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First change the parameter at the system level:

```
alter system set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy' scope='both';
```

This will also update the `spfile` so even if you bounce the db you'll keep your definition.

Second, check for any specific definitions in your client.
If you're using windows go to

1. the registry - check if you have the `nls_timestamp_format` set differently.
2. the `glogin.sql` file - this is a file that executes every time you log into `sqlplus`. there might be an `alter session...` there that changes the system setting.

Comment: Thanks all, for your suggestions. The only thing that i am not able to understand is that why does it changes randomly??

Comment: One can also set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT in an AFTER LOGON trigger; don't forget to check that.

Comment: Hi All, I got to the root of the problem. The problem was that every time i log into the database it was switching on different instances and on one of the instances the variable NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT was different, so everytime i got connected to that instance NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT would differ from the other ones.